# Filter by attribute doesn't bring any products

Tags: magento2, attributes

I have added an attribute (multivalue) in a M2 site that I have. I have linked some products with some attribute values. I have also included the attribute in the layered navigation. I can see the number of products in the parenthesis (on the layered navigation) that the values have but when I click on an attribute value then on the right it says that no products exist with this value.

As you can see from the screenshot Birthday says it has 20 products.

Any ideas?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you reindexed? Is your attribute set "filterable with results"?

Comment: Yes, I have done both.

Comment: I also had the same problem. That's so weird. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I just upgraded to the next release of Magento and it was fixed...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with this change from github. https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/2c62aa376eeed447e632aedb42085c9d255520df